# C# make file read/write from readonly

Tags: c#, file-attributes

If `File.SetAttributes("C:\\myFile.txt", FileAttributes.ReadOnly);` sets a file as read only, how do I set it back to read/write if I need to?

I suspect it would be `FileAttributes.Normal` however will this change any other properties of the file? There isn't an awfully descriptive note on the MSDN site...

> The file is normal and has no other attributes set. This attribute is
>   valid only if used alone.

Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To remove just the `ReadOnly` attribute, you'd do something like this:

```
File.SetAttributes("C:\\myfile.txt", File.GetAttributes("C:\\myfile.txt") & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

This will remove the `ReadOnly` attribute, but preserve any other attributes that already exist on the file.

Comment: I'm guessing `~` reverses the attribute?

Comment: Pretty much - the `~` operator returns a bitwise complement of a given value.  Semantically, what the above says is, "Set the attributes of file `myfile.txt` to the attributes of `myfile.txt` *except for the ReadOnly attribute*."

Comment: If instantiating a `FileInfo` object on your file is an option for you, you can then simply set its `IsReadOnly` property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx

Comment: And if you want to make the file ReadOnly (or assign any other attribute), you need to use | instead of &. For example: `File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);`

Answer (score 20):

File.SetAttributes replaces ALL attributes on the file.

The proper way to set and remove attributes is to first get the attributes, apply changes, and set them.

e.g.

```
var attr = File.GetAttributes(path);

// set read-only
attr = attr | FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
File.SetAttributes(path, attr);

// unset read-only
attr = attr & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
File.SetAttributes(path, attr);
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand this is very late, but I wanted to share my solution hoping it helps others. I needed something similar and the way I accomplished was by setting the `IsReadOnly` property on `FileInfo`.

```
    private void UnsetReadOnlyAttribute(string filePathWithName)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePathWithName);
        if (fileInfo.IsReadOnly)
        {
            fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
        }
    }
```